# Mapbox, Ionic, ngCordova Click Issue

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, mapbox, ngcordova, ionic-view

I'm using:

- Mapbox (v2.2.4),
- Ionic (1.2.4-nightly-1917),
- ngCordova (~0.1.24-alpha).

When I execute `ionic serve` my app works fine (in browser it is working on).

When I execute `ionic emulate ios -l -c` (IOS simulator) and the simulator is on, at first click event fires and my app works fine. 
But at random time (click random more, drag event after), it broken map.on('click') event. Oddly, context Event, and zoom event works fine.

Only map.on('click') event not working on...

Map code is here:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets', {//option streets-satellite
  zoomControl: false,
  attributionControl: false
}).setView([37.3901086, 126.65009319999999], 17);
```

I read http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/tap/ but It works only first time.

=> data-tap-disabled="true" option

and I read https://www.mapbox.com/help/blank-tiles/

=> map.invalidateSize();

but not working on this article...

Comment: this is my repo https://github.com/codeforincheon/reprj/tree/master/www

Comment: i added console.log(click event)!